# Removing Kivy Settings Close Button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Im trying to completely remove the Close Button that is naturally attached to the Kivy Settings object. 
Fear not, I have a navigation so the user wont be stuck or anything.

I have looked through the Kivy documentation to find a way to just call the remove_widget() function on the MenuSideBar close_button object, which looked something like this:

```py
class DevicePicker(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(DevicePicker, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     self.ids.s.interface_cls.remove_widget(self.ids.s.MenuSidebar.close_button)
```

```
<DevicePicker>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Settings:
            id: s
            size: root.height*.8, root.width
```

however that was unsuccessful.

It seems to me there may be someway to just create my own interface without the close_button and attach it to a Settings object, but I dont have any clue how to go about that.

I am using the basic Kivy Settings (class kivy.uix.settings.Settings).

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier readable, could you maybe provide a minimal runnable example?

Comment: @Hultner Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

For a class Settings:
I made this :

```py
self.screen.s = self.screen.ids['settings']
for child in self.screen.s.interface.menu.children:
    if type(child) == Button:
        self.screen.s.interface.menu.remove_widget(child)
```

My kv file

```
Settings:
    size_hint_y: 0.9
    id: settings
```